# Finding out the filename that called my function in PHP

Tags: php, function, debugging

How do I find out the filename of the script that called my function?

For example,

```
function sthing() {
echo __FILE__; // echoes myself
echo __CALLER_FILE__; // echoes the file that called me
}
```

Comment: Could you please give more info about why and to what purpose you would need such functionality? Might be that you are approaching a problem from the wrong end.

Comment: To give an example: require with relative paths loads files from the root dir, even if you invoke require in a subdirectory. Having to prepend __DIR__ to every require call could be hidden away with a wrapper function, but then __DIR__ would point to the wrapper function's directory, not the callee's.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A solution might be to use the [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function : in the backtrace, that kind of information should be present.

Or, as Gordon pointed out in a comment, you can also use [`debug_print_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) if you just want to output that information and not work with it.

For instance, with `temp.php` containing this :

```
<?php
include 'temp-2.php';
my_function();
```

and with `temp-2.php` containing this :

```
<?php
function my_function() {
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}
```

Calling `temp.php` `(i.e. the first script)` from my browser gets me this output :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'file' => string '/.../temp/temp.php' (length=46)
      'line' => int 5
      'function' => string 'my_function' (length=11)
      'args' => 
        array
          empty
```

In there, I have the "`temp.php`" filename -- which is the one in which the function has been called.

Of course, you'll have to test a bit more *(especially in situations where the function is not in the "first level" included file, but in a file included by another one -- not sure `debug_backtrace` will help much, there...)* ; but this might help you get a first idea...

Comment: Maybe add debug_print_backtrace() to the answer as well.

Comment: @Gordon : thanks for the suggestion ; I edited my answer to add that one :-)

Comment: Good answer. Makes it easy to search for the "calling" file starting at the end, just looking for the first file that's different...

Answer (score 17):

Try this code:

```
$key = array_search(__FUNCTION__, array_column(debug_backtrace(), 'function'));
var_dump(debug_backtrace()[$key]['file']);
```

Comment: Perfection. Works as expected.

Comment: If your php doesn't include `array_column`, you may use this polyfill: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422723/1203805

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Pascal Martins's suggestion, you could install the PECL extension [APD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) and use something like [apd_callstack()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apd-callstack.php), which (quoting example)

```
// returns an array containing an array of arrays.

Each array appears to contain:
[0] = function name
[1] = filename that contains function
[2] = *calling* line number in *calling* file
[3] = An array which is usually empty
```

But since this is a PECL extension and might interfere with Zend Optimizer, you might be better off going with debug_backtrace().

Answer (score 3):

2 lines - done:

```
$backfiles=debug_backtrace();
echo $file_called_from=$backfiles[0]['file']; // complete filepath
```

Or to crop out only the filename add the following

```
echo "<Br>";
echo basename($file_called_from); // for only the filename without the path
```

Answer (score 2):

This prints out file_name:line

```
function myFunction() {
  $backfiles = debug_backtrace();
  echo $backfiles[0]['file'] . ':' . $backfiles[0]['line'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the filename as a parameter:

```
function sthing($filename) {
  echo __FILE__; // echoes myself
  echo $filename; // echoes the file that called me
}
```

When you call the function you pass the magic constant **FILE**:

```
sthing(__FILE__);
```