# How can I get the name of the script that called a function?

Tags: php

I have a log() method and want to log the name of the script that called it. How is that possible in PHP?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935867/finding-out-the-filename-that-called-my-function-in-php/1935902

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the calling environment, you should have a look at [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), and [$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/understanding-_serverphp_self-php_self-_serverrequest_uri-and-_serverscript_name-in-php-and-when-to-use-what/)

`debug_backtrace()` will give you a stack trace of the includes and function calls so far, and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will tell you the currently executing script, which is easier and might work just as well for what you want. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will pretty much always be the script that was called from the browser, for example, if you had `blah.com/admin.php` and `blah.com/articles.php` that both called `/pages.php` to get a list of the pages saved in a blog or something, and something went wrong -- the log would tell you whether `admin.php` or `articles.php` was calling the script. But if `pages.php` included `functions.php` which included `libs.php` and libs.php failed, and you wanted to know that `functions.php` included it, this wouldn't work -- the log would still show the script that started the including (`admin.php` or `articles.php`). In this case you would use `debug_backtrace()`.

Comment: Thanks for `debug_backtrace()`. It is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function : in it's output, you should find what you are looking for ;-)

You can take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935867/finding-out-the-filename-that-called-my-function-in-php/1935875#1935875) I posted a couple of days ago, for more informations, and an example.

Comment: look at all the 'informations' in that link! I'm digging informations! lol

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [debug_baktrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace).

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
print_r($backtrace[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [debug_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get an associative array containing the complete callstack and examine the array to pull the details you're interested from it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given a very low-tech answer would be to or append 
_ _ FILE _ _ or  basename() to a string which is being logged.
(had to add spaces to double underscore in FILE to make it display)