# Php, is it possible to get the name of the program calling my script

Tags: php

For security reasons, I would like to make sure my script is called by a specific cgi program.

Is it possible to get the name of the program that called the script ?

TIA

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967158/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-script-that-called-a-function

Comment: That was fast ! I am going to try right away. Gracias, Álvaro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the name of the script that called a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967158/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-script-that-called-a-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out the filename that called my function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935867/finding-out-the-filename-that-called-my-function-in-php)

Comment: Well, it is not that conclusive. Thank you all, but I cannot find the name of the program that called my script by the methods described at the links.

Comment: I will probably do what is suggested in one of the posts, to pass the name of the program in parameters. Once encrypted, it should be alright.