# Alternate (polyfill) for array_column()

Tags: php, arrays, function, polyfills, array-column

I have used `array_column()` in a project, and after uploading I found out that only PHP 5.5 or above support this function, and I think the hosting I use don't support PHP 5.5 or above.

So I want to know if is there any alternate to fix this error?

This is how I am using `array_column` in my project:

```
array_count_values(array_column(json_decode(json_encode($queryResultArray), true), $idForBar));
```

This is working fine in my local xampp and wampp also, but on server it is giving issue. Looking any alternate function or solution.

Comment: wtf are you sure about `json_decode(json_encode(` ? Like, why??

Comment: Well you know what my solution would be: Upgrade PHP to 5.5, or move to a host that actually supports development and moving forward!

Comment: well, just break it into parts and just do it without it. its not complicated.

Comment: if you want a library solution https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Comment: @MightyPork
i used json_decode(json_encode cuz i wanted to convert object array to associated array. i know its not a good way but it gets the job done. but i didnt opened the question for json question.

Comment: @MightyPork `json_decode(json_encode(` is OK, because there is `json_decode(json_encode(...., true));` do you see? check the documentation...

Comment: @Legionar not saying it doesn't work, but it looks like a very inefficient and hacky solution

Comment: @MightyPork - hacky, arguable, but actually very efficient

Comment: Your variable is named `$queryResultArray`... - may I ask, are you trying to apply this function to the result set of an SQL query?

Comment: @silkfire
no, that is just the name query. its not actuall query, it includes the result fethed from db.. :)

Comment: @SizzlingCode If it's the result fetched from your DB, in `PDO` you can use a special fetch mode which will solve this entire problem for you. How does your query look like?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Add your own function `array_column` if you PHP version does not support it:

```
<?php
if (! function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $input, $columnKey, $indexKey = null) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($input as $value) {
            if ( !array_key_exists($columnKey, $value)) {
                trigger_error("Key \"$columnKey\" does not exist in array");
                return false;
            }
            if (is_null($indexKey)) {
                $array[] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
            else {
                if ( !array_key_exists($indexKey, $value)) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not exist in array");
                    return false;
                }
                if ( ! is_scalar($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not contain scalar value");
                    return false;
                }
                $array[$value[$indexKey]] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

[Reference:](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Comment: Whats the difference between your implementation and Ben Ramsey's https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php

Comment: Better to put the function array_column() in an include file and use require at the top of your code. This way it only gets included if the function does not exist. Otherwise  php will complain about redefinition at parse time if the function already exists.

Comment: @user603749, there is alrady check if function does not exist, then our code. :)

Comment: Additionally, you can just use `array_column()` with objects if you're using `PHP7+`. You can visit this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#refsect1-function.array-column-changelog

Comment: This function did not work if returning values are array's.  Used @doub1ejack suggested solution and it worked perfectly.  His suggestion was to use the actual code form the PHP 5.5+ library [here](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Comment: If support of objects needed, this can be used: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#119754

Answer (score 24):

You can also use `array_map()` function if you haven't `array_column()` because of PHP<5.5:

Example:

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    )
);

array_column($a, 'last_name');
```

Becomes:

```
array_map(function($element) {
  return $element['last_name'];
}, $a);
```

So it your case the code will be:

```
array_count_values(
  array_map(function($arr) use ($idForBar) {
    return $arr[$idForBar];
  }, $queryResultArray)
);
```

This above is working on PHP 5.3.0 and above!

If you have < PHP 5.3.0, as you wrote PHP 5.2.17, just use simple function:

```
function get_field_data($array, $field, $idField = null) {
    $_out = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        if ($idField == null) {
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                $_out[] = $value[$field];
            }
        }
        else {
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                $_out[$value[$idField]] = $value[$field];
            }
        }
        return $_out;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }           
}
```

And the usage:

```
$output = get_field_data($queryResultArray, $idForBar);
```

Comment: This is not only functionality of `array_column()`

Comment: @AlmaDo So? It's the only one *needed* in this case.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the alternative code of array_column(), it's simple just paste below line and replace your variable.

Code:

```
array_map(function($element){return $element['last_name'];}, $a);
```

Comment: @Legionar gave this advice back in 2014.  Why did you post this redundant answer?

Answer (score 4):

Using [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead, something like:

```
array_count_values(
    array_map(
        function($value) use ($idForBar) {
            return $value[$idForBar];
        },
        json_decode(
            json_encode($queryResultArray),
            true
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: im really really greatful to your reply but i got stucked in other problem after using your code.
`syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'`
To which i searched google and i found out anonymous functions supported after 5.3.0??
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723748/php-version-5-2-14-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-function-expecting`
How to tackle this??

Comment: What version of PHP are you actually running? If you get that error, it suggests a very old, unsupported version (PHP < 5.3) that doesn't support closures; in which case, read Niet's comment on your question

Comment: I just checked with `phpinfo();`
server php version is `PHP Version 5.2.17` :(

Comment: Sir Any solution possible for 5.2.17?

Comment: @SizzlingCode If you have < PHP 5.3.0, as you wrote PHP 5.2.17, just use simple function, as I updated my answer...

Answer (score 4):

You can always use another implementation of function [array_column](http://wajeel.ru/blog/analog-zamena-funkcii-array-column.html)

```
if (!function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $array, $columnKey, $indexKey = null)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array as $subArray) {
            if (!is_array($subArray)) {
                continue;
            } elseif (is_null($indexKey) && array_key_exists($columnKey, $subArray)) {
                $result[] = $subArray[$columnKey];
            } elseif (array_key_exists($indexKey, $subArray)) {
                if (is_null($columnKey)) {
                    $result[$subArray[$indexKey]] = $subArray;
                } elseif (array_key_exists($columnKey, $subArray)) {
                    $result[$subArray[$indexKey]] = $subArray[$columnKey];
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you took the polyfill and ripped out the `trigger_errors`?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [official recommendation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for PHP versions that don't support `array_column()` under the "see also" section:

> [» Recommended userland implementation for PHP lower than 5.5](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Their recommendation is another `if (!function_exists('array_column'))` approach, but the code is actually extracted from the array_column library and is a little more generalized than the examples on this page.