# How to pull specific key values from array inside array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have array output like below,

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [file_name] => test.pdf 
                       [file_type] => application/pdf 
                       [file_path] => /Applications/AMPPS/www/testing/uploads/attachments/2/
[1] => Array ( [file_name] => test1.pdf 
                       [file_type] => application/pdf 
                       [file_path] => /Applications/AMPPS/www/testing/uploads/attachments/2/ )
```

How can i pull a new array like below

```
Array( [0] => test.pdf [1] => test1.pdf)
```

Background,

I am doing multiple file upload using Codeigniter, my files are uploading and getting return data array, i want only file names to be send back to my view, so need to pull file names of files which are uploaded,

Any suggestions, hints?

Thanks,

Comment: sorry there wan typo in key

Answer (score 4):

Use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like,

```
$new_array = array_column ($your_array, 'file_name');
```

---

If using PHP version < 5.5, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422723/3113793)

Comment: @Uchiha it will help the OP. May be That is a typo.

Comment: @Uchiha *sorry there wan typo in key*

Comment: @Viral, how to pull only array values without key? means array('test.pdf', 'test1.pdf')?

Comment: Did you tried the code it'll do exactly what you need @rjcode

Comment: @Uchiha, yes that worked but i feel i need to remove keys as well, to process that further is easy.

Comment: In this world, there doesn't exist array without keys. In `array('test.pdf', 'test1.pdf')` string `test.pdf` has `0` as key and the other have `1` as key

Comment: One simple question post the `print_r` values of _`array('test.pdf', 'test1.pdf')`_ and what does this means _`Array( [0] => test.pdf [1] => test1.pdf)`_ within your posted question @rjcode

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arrResult = array();
foreach ($arrGiven as $key => $value) {
    $arrResult[] = $value['file_name'];
}
```

$arrGiven is the first array from which you want to extract the data. $arrResult will contain the data like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = array();
foreach($old as $entrie){
  $new[] = $entrie['file_name'];
}
```

This will go through all the entreis of the old array, and put the `file_name` of each in a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
$files = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $files[] = $array[$key]['file_name'];
}
print_r($files);
```