# in php remove keys and convert into a flat arrays

Tags: php, arrays

[image: I have an array as the image shows]
and I want to remove the key "holiday_date" and get a falt arry
    array('2010-01-01','2010-01-02',...)
is that a smarter way to do this rather then a loop?

Comment: Not clear enough. Please add some example of what you want and what have you tried to achieve this.

Comment: Could you show any code you're having.
We're not here to just make the code you want, you have to try yourself, and if you're having problems, then ask for help here :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pull specific key values from array inside array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863160/how-to-pull-specific-key-values-from-array-inside-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php),

```
$tmp = array_column($tmp, 'holiday_date');
```

This will pull out 'holiday_date' values from your internal arrays, and we are storing them in `$tmp` itself, so after this line, `$tmp` will formed as you need.

---

Another Example: consider the below array,

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ));
```

Applying, `array_column()` as below,

```
array_column($records, 'first_name');
```

will return,

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Sally
)
```

---

If using PHP version < 5.5, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422723/3113793) quick implementation of `array_column()`.

Comment: this is exactly what i want to do, unfortunately my php is 5.3 and do not have this function.>If using PHP version < 5.5, refer this, thank you I have resolved this problem.